# VS Code change syntax highlighting inside the <script> tag

Tags: javascript, python, visual-studio-code, brython

Can I change the syntax recognition inside the   tag from javascript to python?

```
    <script type="text/python">

        def foo():
            return 'Hello!'

    </script>
```

I use Brython for frontend, and it would be very convenient for me.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a known issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25920

The bug report is from 3 years ago but still has not been fixed.

Comment: Seems like it is closed by this recommendation: Brython support · Issue #95827 · microsoft/vscode https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95827

Comment: I just submitted a feature request here: Syntax hiliting etc for Brython? · Issue #15067 · microsoft/vscode-python https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15067